# enter key issue of vim emulation in IntelliJ IDE editor

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, enter

I am using IntelliJ IDE.

and I like vim editor emulation.

So I enabled vim emulation mode.

But when using vim emulation, I have a discomfort.

When I [enter] in vim normal mode(ESC mode),  I(insert mode) + [enter] key generation will be more good to me but [enter] key do not work.
(This is also normal condition in vim )

I wish that  i(insert mode) + [enter] key would be generated when I [enter] in vim normal mode(ESC mode),
and in insert mode, [enter] key would generate normal [enter] key .

If this feature is possible , please inform me !!!

Comment: You can request the feature at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM elaborating on your use-case. See also the discussion in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-752

Comment: I have read the issue. I also agree that the feature is not compatible with normal VIM. But when using IDE Editor(Vim emulation)  If on normal mode [Enter]|[Delete] Key input could generate I[insert mode] + [Enter]|[Delete], It will be so good to use in my case !!!